# VPN Server not accepting all traffic

Tags: windows-7, macos, vpn, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a server where I host my VPN (Windows Server 2008 R2) and I can access all the websites that are hosted on the same server, but any time I try and make an internet request, the connection fails.

The Client is Mac OS X 10.8.1 with the `Send all traffic` box checked.

I also tried to connect with a PC (Windows 7) and another PC (Windows 8 RC) but neither of them could connect to the internet, but again, hosted websites worked fine.

As far as I can tell, its not a DNS issue, because DNS resolves fine when `nslookup` or `dig` are run. (See edit)

I even tried accessing `http://208.69.38.205/` (The OpenDNS rescue page) and that wont load.

On the server, the VPN is setup with `Network Policy and Access` >> `Routing and Remote Services` and a custom configuration of VPN only.

I really dont want a split-tunnel type connection.

Bottom Line: Is there any way to resolve this and/or did I setup the VPN server wrong.

**--EDIT--**

I was wrong. DNS does not resolve unless the server is the acting DNS Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by crating a NAT interface.

Steps to solve. Assumes that Routing and Remote services (RaRS) has been setup with a custom configuration of VPN **ONLY**

1. Open RaRS
2. Open IPv4 (or IPv6 if you use it)
3. Right click on General
4. `New routing protocol`
5. Select NAT
6. Click OK
7. Under IPv4/6 open NAT
8. At the toolbar at the top, select Action -> New Interface...
9. Select the Connection that connects to the internet, **NOT INTERNAL**
10. Change the Interface Type to `Public interface connected to the Internet`
11. Check `Enable NAT on this interface`
12. Apply -> OK
13. Connect with a client computer and test it out.

I recommend testing by going to google, and typing `whats my ip` if the ip is of the server, it works!

This question had only been up for a few minutes, but I have been trying to get this to work for days. I just hope that this can help somebody else.